# Gmail API: removing all emails from a label with Google Apps Script is rather slow

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I use this to remove all emails in a label:

```
function emptyLabel() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("label_name");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i].removeLabel(label);
  }
}
```

but it's rather slow (more than 1min30 for a label with a few hundred messages), since it iterates on all messages.

Another option would be to delete completely the label, and recreate it, but this would change the Gmail GUI settings for this label (color, etc.), so it's not really an option.

**Question: how to remove all emails from a label efficiently in Gmail with Google Apps Script?**

Answer (score 2):

### There are faster loops than the conventional `for` - see [here](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/04/16/benchmark-loop-for-array-processing-using-google-apps-script/)

You can increase the speed by modifying your code to

```js
function emptyLabel() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("label_name");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  threads.forEach(function(thread){
    thread.removeLabel(label);
  })
}
```

### Also, the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api) is usually faster than GmailApp

After [enabling](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) it in the Apps Script editor, you can usually speed up your request with a combination of [users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) and [users.messages.batchModify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/batchModify):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var messages = Gmail.Users.Messages.list("me", {"labelIds":"label_name"}).messages;
  var ids = [];
  messages.forEach(function(message){ids.push(message.id)});
  Gmail.Users.Messages.batchModify({"ids":ids, "removeLabelIds":["label_name"]}, "me");

}
```